# how many test records can you create in a test class?

Tags: apex, unit-test

I'm trying to simulate the batch that will happen in production. I'm going to process every record that comes from our sObject "Listing". When I trying to run this code:

```
@isTest
private class ListingUrlBatchTest {

    @testSetup 
    static void setup() {

        Account seller = new Account (Name = 'Test Seller');

        insert seller;

        List<pba__Listing__c> listings = new List<pba__Listing__c>();

        for(Integer i = 0; i < 9999; i++) {
            listings.add(new pba__Listing__c (
                Stage__c               = 'Auction',
                Seller__c              = seller.Id,
                pba__Address_pb__c     = '1234 Main St. Unit ' + i,
                pba__City_pb__c        = 'Woodland Hills',
                pba__PostalCode_pb__c  = '91313',
                pba__StateCode_pb__c   = 'CA',
                pba__Country_pb__c     = 'USA'
            ));
        }

        insert listings;  
    }

    static testmethod void batchTest() {        
        Test.startTest();
        Database.executeBatch(new ListingUrlBatch());
        Test.stopTest();
        System.assertEquals(9998, [SELECT count() FROM pba__Listing__c]);
    }   
}
```

I get this error

> System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded

I know in the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm) you can processes 10,000 records per dml statement. Is there any way around this error? I'd like to have 30,000 test records in my test.

Comment: There isn't much point in using such a large number of records. In a test the batchable `execute` is only allowed to be called once so the number of records needs to be less than or equal to the batch size. As you are not specifying that (its a second parameter to `Database.executeBatch`) it is defaulting to 200. Trying to use a very large number of records doesn't get you very far in a test. I'd stick to 200.

Comment: Generally the main purpose of testing with a very large record set (many multiples or an order of magnitude larger than a standard transaction set) is to evaluate query performance in volume. That really needs to happen in a full copy org - you can't create that condition in a unit test.

Otherwise, as @KeithC says, 200-ish records should suffice. You may find in a real-world org that even that many records can produce timeouts, depending on your trigger complexity. I've worked in orgs where you can't insert more than 20 or so.

Comment: @DavidReed I worked in an org where you were allowed to insert ... two contacts before you hit the CPU limit, lol.